# How can I change the default sender address of my hosting server?

Tags: php, cpanel

I use the php::mail() function in my scripts to send out emails from the server. While I can change the From header, the sender still shows as a default address from the hosting server (something@server.thehost.com)

Where in the cpanel settings can I change this address?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the fifth [`mail()`](http://php.net/mail) argument: `'-f your@sender.address'`

Comment: I can change the From address, that is not a problem. Its the sender address I want to change. To clarify, thunderbird has a sender and a from. The sender still shows up as something@server.thehost.com